# laravel lighthouse, how to check query depth, query complexity

Tags: php, laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I check the security(https://www.howtographql.com/advanced/4-security/) before deploying the lighthouse on the production server.
so i decided to check query depth, query complexity

In the lighthouse documentation, they mentioned `config/lighthouse.php`,

```php
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Security
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Control how Lighthouse handles security related query validation.
| Read more at https://webonyx.github.io/graphql-php/security/
|
*/
'security' => [
    'max_query_complexity' => \GraphQL\Validator\Rules\QueryComplexity::DISABLED,
    'max_query_depth' => \GraphQL\Validator\Rules\QueryDepth::DISABLED,
    'disable_introspection' => \GraphQL\Validator\Rules\DisableIntrospection::DISABLED,
],
```

and recommeded to read https://webonyx.github.io/graphql-php/security/

in this link, they give some examples,

```php
use GraphQL\GraphQL;
use GraphQL\Validator\Rules\QueryComplexity;
use GraphQL\Validator\DocumentValidator;

$rule = new QueryComplexity($maxQueryComplexity = 100);
DocumentValidator::addRule($rule);

GraphQL::executeQuery(/*...*/);
```

```php
use GraphQL\GraphQL;
use GraphQL\Validator\Rules\QueryDepth;
use GraphQL\Validator\DocumentValidator;

$rule = new QueryDepth($maxDepth = 10);
DocumentValidator::addRule($rule);

GraphQL::executeQuery(/*...*/);
```

but how to apply these in lighthouse?

in first time, i wrote those code to `ExampleQuery.php(php artisan lighthouse:query ExampleQuery)`

```php
final class ExampleQuery
{
    public function __invoke(_, array $args)
    {
        $rule = new QueryComplexity(2);
        DocumentValidator::addRule($rule);

        $rule2 = new QueryDepth(2);
        DocumentValidator::addRule($rule2);

        return [
            ...
        ];
    }
}
```

but that can`t catch any problems.

I think lighthouse start in `vendor/nuwave/.../GraphQLController.php`
So i can't execute `GraphQL::executeQuery(/*...*/);`

and `@complexity` directive not working,
`@complexity(resolver: "App\\Security\\ComplexityAnalyzer@userPosts")` doesn`t call userPosts function.

```php
class ComplexityAnalyzer {

    public function userPosts(int $childrenComplexity, array $args): int  // not called
    {
        $postComplexity = $args['includeFullText']
            ? 3
            : 2;
        \Log::Debug($postComplexity); // not called
        return $childrenComplexity * $postComplexity;

    }
}
```

what am i missing..? please help make me sleep comfortable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is already implemented, you have to only set the values.

```
'security' => [
        'max_query_complexity' => 100,
        'max_query_depth' => 10,
    ],
```

The complexity score calculation can be modified for each field with [@complexity](https://lighthouse-php.com/master/api-reference/directives.html#complexity) directive.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Then, is there no way to apply those thing each directive..?

Comment: For the depth index, it doesn't make sense because it is calculated based on the whole query and how many levels it had. But you can change the complexity score calculation with [@complexity](https://lighthouse-php.com/master/api-reference/directives.html#complexity) directive for each field.